# Non-null assertion operator is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

Runtime error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

```
if (!this.havingMultipleProjects) {//having only 1 project or not at all
  if (this.authenticationProvider.member.projects != null) 
this.projectProvider.projectId = this.authenticationProvider.member!.projects[0]!.id;
   }
```

Can you tell me how to avoid above error? I have used [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#non-null-assertion-operator). But still, it gives the above error. Any clue?

Comment: The operator is telling *the compiler* that this value will definitely have a value at runtime. However, TS only does its check at compile time, at runtime the type system is not in place, as it's just the compiled JS code that is running. You said "trust me, there is going to be a value" but there isn't one.

Comment: Tl;dr; the typechecker tells you it cannot ascertain, that the expression is not null/undefined. You tell it "i am sure it is not null/undefined". It is undefined. It crashes at runtime. You are confused.

Comment: @VLAZ How to avoid this error then?

Comment: @ASDFGerte How to avoid this error then?

Comment: Check for null at runtime.

Comment: Make sure that it is actually not undefined. The primary issue is, that for some reason, `this.authenticationProvider.member.projects[0]` is `undefined`, aka the property doesnt exist.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I know the problem. But what is the solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in comments, the null assertion operator.... **The operator is telling the compiler that this value will definitely have a value at runtime**, so during runtime error will occur.

So the error....

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

obviously then...

```
this.authenticationProvider.member.projects[0]
```

is `undefined`. Which is fine, it passes the if you have, since you are not checking the length of the array:

```
if (this.authenticationProvider.member.projects != null)
```

So your code passes if `projects` is `[]`

I would just do `if (this.authenticationProvider.member.projects)` it includes the check for if it even exists, covering `null`, `undefined`, `false` altogether. Also then after that do a check that there is actually an object in the array, so your `if` statement could therefore look like:

```
if (this.authenticationProvider.member.projects && this.authenticationProvider.member.projects.length)
```

if you are unsure that even `member` exists, you should do an additional check for that...

```
if (this.authenticationProvider.member && 
    this.authenticationProvider.member.projects && 
    this.authenticationProvider.member.projects.length)
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation and it works without having any dependency on library. i.e TS version and etc

Comment: No problem, glad I could help to clarify things :)

Answer (score 2):

The `non-null assertion operator` does **not** ensure that you will get no error if your data is 'incorrect'.
It works on the types, **not** on the actual data.
It's just for creating/adjusting your types.

However, if you want to simply get `undefined`(thus, no error will be thrown) in case `projects[0]` does not exist, you can use the [optional chaining operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/), which will land in **3.7**.

So, you will be able to use it like this:

```js
this.authenticationProvider.member?.projects[0]?.id
```

and if `projects[0]` is `undefined`, the entire expression will evaluate to `undefined` and you will get no error.

Comment: Maybe if you do `if (this.authenticationProvider.member.projects.length) {  }` will work?

Comment: If you see my code I have already done that. i.e. `if (this.authenticationProvider.member.projects != null)`

Comment: Imagine you have an array `const arr = []`; `arr !== null` will always be **true**. The problem is that you are trying to access `arr[0].prop` which will be undefined. By doing `if (arr.length) { }` you are making sure that the array has at least one element so you can access `arr[0].prop` more safely.

Comment: How about this? `if (this.authenticationProvider.member != null && this.authenticationProvider.member.projects != null && this.authenticationProvider.member.projects.length > 0)`

Comment: In my opinion, `this.authenticationProvider.member.projects != null` is redundant. Also, keep in mind that `undefined != null` equals to false.

Comment: Why do you think this is redundant? `this.authenticationProvider.member.projects != null` What if `projects` also undefined? This is perfectly fine for me no? `undefined != null equals to false` i.e. I don't need to go to inner statement then.